# Azure front door custom domain bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code, azure-front-door

Here is my set up:

I have a bicep repository that has bicep templates which are called as modules in the applications which need them.

My front door (classic) template from bicep repo:

```
param frontDoorName string
param backEndAddress string
param frontEndEndPointName string
param backEndPoolName string

var loadBalancingSettingsName = ''
var healthProbeSettingsName = ''
var routingRuleName = ''

resource myFrontDoorResource 'Microsoft.Network/frontDoors@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'

    frontendEndpoints: [
      {
        name: frontEndEndPointName
        properties: {
          hostName: '${frontDoorName}.azurefd.net'
          sessionAffinityEnabledState: 'Disabled'
        }
      }
    ]

    loadBalancingSettings: [
      {
        name: loadBalancingSettingsName
        properties: {
          sampleSize: 4
          successfulSamplesRequired: 2
        }
      }
    ]

    healthProbeSettings: [
      {
        name: healthProbeSettingsName
        properties: {
          path: '/'
          protocol: 'Http'
          intervalInSeconds: 120
        }
      }
    ]

    backendPools: [
      {
        name: backEndPoolName
        properties: {
          backends: [
            {
              address: backEndAddress
              backendHostHeader: backEndAddress
              httpPort: 80
              httpsPort: 443
              weight: 100
              priority: 1
              enabledState: 'Enabled'
            }
          ]
          loadBalancingSettings: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/loadBalancingSettings', frontDoorName, loadBalancingSettingsName)
          }
          healthProbeSettings: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/healthProbeSettings', frontDoorName, healthProbeSettingsName)
          }
        }
      }
    ]

    routingRules: [
      {
        name: routingRuleName
        properties: {
          frontendEndpoints: [
            {
              id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/frontEndEndpoints', frontDoorName, frontEndEndPointName)
            }
          ]
          acceptedProtocols: [
            'Http'
            'Https'
          ]
          patternsToMatch: [
            '/*'
          ]
          routeConfiguration: {
            '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Azure.FrontDoor.Models.FrontdoorForwardingConfiguration'
            forwardingProtocol: 'MatchRequest'
            backendPool: {
              id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/backEndPools', frontDoorName, backEndPoolName)
            }
          }
          enabledState: 'Enabled'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Module called from application

```
module myFrontDoorModule 'azurefrontdoor.bicep' = {
 name: ''
 params: {
   frontDoorName: ''
   backEndAddress: ''
   frontEndEndpPintName: ''
   backEndPoolName: ''
 }
}
```

Now I have added one custom domain and my routing rule is updated to use the custom domain value in Frontends/domains field. Assuming I will have more custom domains, backend pools, routing rules I need help in improving it to accept array of such input params to make this dynamic in nature for other applications to use. Can someone please suggest/help me how to go about improving the above shared set up?

Updated bicep

```
param frontDoorName string

var loadBalancingSettingsName = 'loadBalancingSettings'
var healthProbeSettingsName = 'healthProbeSettings'

var endpoints = [
  {
    name: 'frontEndEndpoint'
    hostName: '${frontDoorName}.azurefd.net'
  }
  {
    name: 'abc'
    hostName: 'abc.com'
  }
  {
    name: 'xyz'
    hostName: 'xyz.com'
  }
]

var backendPoolArray = [
  {
    backendPoolName: 'firstbepool'
    backendAddress: 'abc.azurewebsites.net'
  }
  {
    backendPoolName: 'secondbepool'
    backendAddress: 'xyz.azurewebsites.net'
  }
]

var routingRules = [
  {
    routingRuleName: 'routingRuleOne'
    backendPoolName: 'firstbepool'
    endpointName: 'abc'
  }
  {
    routingRuleName: 'routingRuleTwo'
    backendPoolName: 'secondbepool'
    endpointName: 'xyz'
  }
]

resource frontDoorResource 'Microsoft.Network/frontDoors@2021-06-01' = {
  name: frontDoorName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'

    frontendEndpoints: [for endpoint in endpoints: {
      name: endpoint.name
      properties: {
        hostName: endpoint.hostName
        sessionAffinityEnabledState: 'Disabled'
      }
    }]

    loadBalancingSettings: [
      {
        name: loadBalancingSettingsName
        properties: {
          sampleSize: 4
          successfulSamplesRequired: 2
        }
      }
    ]

    healthProbeSettings: [
      {
        name: healthProbeSettingsName
        properties: {
          path: '/'
          protocol: 'Http'
          intervalInSeconds: 120
        }
      }
    ]

    backendPools: [for backendPool in backendPoolArray: {
      name: backendPool.backendPoolName
      properties: {
        backends: [
          {
            address: backendPool.backendAddress
            backendHostHeader: backendPool.backendAddress
            httpPort: 80
            httpsPort: 443
            weight: 100
            priority: 1
            enabledState: 'Enabled'
          }
        ]
        loadBalancingSettings: {
          id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/loadBalancingSettings', frontDoorName, loadBalancingSettingsName)
        }
        healthProbeSettings: {
          id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/healthProbeSettings', frontDoorName, healthProbeSettingsName)
        }
      }
    }]

    routingRules: [for routingRule in routingRules: {
      name: routingRule.routingRuleName
      properties: {
        frontendEndpoints: [
          {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/frontEndEndpoints', frontDoorName, routingRule.endpointName)
          }
        ]
        acceptedProtocols: [
          'Http'
          'Https'
        ]
        patternsToMatch: [
          '/*'
        ]
        routeConfiguration: {
          '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Azure.FrontDoor.Models.FrontdoorForwardingConfiguration'
          forwardingProtocol: 'MatchRequest'
          backendPool: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/backEndPools', frontDoorName, routingRule.backendPoolName)
          }
        }
        enabledState: 'Enabled'
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if any additional information is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create two or more custom domains or routing rules or any resource properties, you need to initialize an array of objects, declare it in module bicep file, then traverse it using `for` loop in the bicep file.

*I modified your code as below.*

```bash
param frontdoorprefix string ='jah'
param backEndAddress string = 'address1'
param frontEndEndPointName string = 'endpointnew'
param backEndPoolName string = 'backendpool1'
param customDomain array
param backendPools array
param routingRules array
var loadBalancingSettingsName = 'newlbj'
var healthProbeSettingsName = 'probesj'
var routingRuleName = 'newruleja'
var frontDoorName = '${frontdoorprefix}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

resource myFrontDoorResource 'Microsoft.Network/frontDoors@2021-06-01' =  {
  name: frontDoorName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'

    frontendEndpoints: [
      for frontendEndpoint in customDomains : {
        name: '{frontEndEndPoint}1'
        properties: {
          hostName: '${frontendEndpoint}.azurefd.net'
          sessionAffinityEnabledState: 'Disabled'
        }
      }
    ]

    loadBalancingSettings: [
      {
        name: loadBalancingSettingsName
        properties: {
          sampleSize: 4
          successfulSamplesRequired: 2
        }
      }
    ]

    healthProbeSettings: [
      {
        name: healthProbeSettingsName
        properties: {
          path: '/'
          protocol: 'Http'
          intervalInSeconds: 120
        }
      }
    ]

    backendPools: [
      for backendPool in backendPools : {
        name: backendPool.name
        properties: {
          backends: [
            {
              address: backEndAddress
              backendHostHeader: backEndAddress
              httpPort: 80
              httpsPort: 443
              weight: 100
              priority: 1
              enabledState: 'Enabled'
            }
          ]
          loadBalancingSettings: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/loadBalancingSettings', frontDoorName, loadBalancingSettingsName)
          }
          healthProbeSettings: {
            id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/healthProbeSettings', frontDoorName, healthProbeSettingsName)
          }
        }
      }
    ]

    routingRules: [
      {
        name: routingRuleName
        properties: {
          frontendEndpoints: [
            {
              id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/frontEndEndpoints', frontDoorName, frontEndEndPointName)
            }
          ]
          acceptedProtocols: [
            'Http'
            'Https'
          ]
          patternsToMatch: [
            '/*'
          ]
          routeConfiguration: {
            '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Azure.FrontDoor.Models.FrontdoorForwardingConfiguration'
            forwardingProtocol: 'MatchRequest'
            backendPool: {
              id: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/backEndPools', frontDoorName, backEndPoolName)
            }
          }
          enabledState: 'Enabled'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

module.bicep:

```bash
module myFrontDoorModule 'azurefrontdoor.bicep' = {
 name: 'xxxxx'
params: {
    customDomain: [
      {
        name: 'Domain1'
        hostName: 'xxxx.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'Domain2'
        hostName: 'xxxx.com'
      }
    ]
  }
}
        //Add other required array's same as above format.
```

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jahnavi I was doing something similar but I have a couple of questions in the answer you posted: 1. frontendEndpoints for each custom domain will it append azurefd.net? Is it required? 2. In backendpool and routingrules is it not required to differentiate on basis of the custom domains? Can you update your answer assuming the front door name to be myfrontdoor.azurefd.net, custom domains (2): abc.com and xyz.com, 2 backend pool and 2 routing rules where front end host is abc.com and xyz.com for appservice1.azurewebsites.net and appservice2.azurewebsites.net respectively

Comment: If you would like I can post my version and may be that will help you understand my confusion, please let me know

Comment: I have updated my question to add my version of file. The doubts I have: 1. Do loadBalancingSettings and healthProbeSettings need any properties to be updated or wll they work fine for both iterations? 2. backendPools and routingRules: I have used some properties from variables for each iterations. Do they need any change? Please review and let me know if I have done something incorrectly

Comment: 1. `loadBalancingSettings` and `healthProbeSettings` doesn't need any properties to be updated and it's good to go. 

2. Same as 1st one. `backendPools` and `routingRules` are also given correctly. @Lucky

Comment: Thank you so much @Jahnavi. I have one more question: Assume if I want to use the same front door for all my lower environments (dev, test etc.) what do I do? Is it possible to decide values of paramaters on the basis of values of other paramaters? For e.g. I can introduce parameter file for each environment and use its value to determine the value of all my array parameters. Or can I have the array parameters in the bicep parameters json file? If yes, how? I am not finding any suggestion online.